# Remove all occurences of an element in a one-way linked list

Tags: c, list, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have spent several hours writing a function that - given a linked list one-way list, will remove all of the occurrences of a given element. This is the function I have managed to write:

```
void remove_by_value(struct Node **head, int value) {
    while( *head!=NULL && (*head)->value == value ) {
        struct Node *tmp = *head;
        if((*head)->next != NULL)
            *head = (*head)->next;
        else
            *head = NULL;
        free(tmp);
    }

    struct Node *iterator = *head;
    while(iterator->next != NULL) {
        if(iterator->next->value == value) {
            struct Node *tmp = iterator;
            iterator = iterator->next;
            free(tmp);
            continue;
        }
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }
}
```

In my example, I am using a simple list which looks like this: `2->1->1` and the output of my program after I run `remove_by_value(&head, 1)`:

```
0 
1242177584 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Which is a far cry from the desired effect. The problem is that I don't understand where my mistake is. This is the algorithm that I wanted to apply:

1. Check if the head of this list has the desired value. If so, move the head to the right and remove the first node. Repeat it until the value of the new head is different than the argument of this function
2. Check if the value of the next node equals the desired value. If yes, delete this node and link the current node with the node after the one that has been deleted.

I know that my algorithm is not perfect - for example it does not handle the case when the node does not point to anything. But the kernel of the matter is that I don't understand why my program behaves like this. Could you give me some suggestions? Is there a better way to write this algorithm?

EDIT: 
I thought it might be important and so I have decided to include my print function as it could cause some potential memory leaks in light of my previous function:

```
void print(struct Node *head) {
    while(head != NULL) {
        printf("%d \n", head->value);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you should manually walk through your code for the example you have given in the problem statement(`2->1->1`). Your code fails the first condition check of your first `while` loop only (TRUE && FALSE) i.e. it does not enter your first `while` loop at all. And in the second `while` loop you free `tmp` which is currently pointing to `2`

Comment: I'm just curious. Why would your program have an output? What does the 0 and 1242177584 mean?

Comment: @leyanpan
I ran the function and then I ran the print function which I've included.

Comment: You should also spend several hours debugging your code, stepping through, inspecting values etc.  That's how developing software has to be:(

Comment: @AditiRawat I have changed the second loop, not it at least does not free the "2" node, but this still prints some strange addresses. 
`while(iterator->next != NULL) {
  if(iterator->next->value == value) {
   struct Node *tmp = iterator->next;
   iterator = iterator->next->next;
   free(tmp);
   continue;
  }
  iterator = iterator->next;
 }`

Comment: why did you `free(tmp)`? it caused your dump. Also your head could be NULL,so the iterator, so there is another source for your dump. In general you overcomplicated it.

Comment: @Aemilius you should post a [MCVE] and tell us what the input of your program is (if any).

Comment: @MichaelWalz  
Thanks. I am new to SE but I will surely remember for the next time:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work, too complicated to verify though. Will delete the post if it doesn't.

```
void remove_by_value(struct Node **head, int value) {
    while( *head!=NULL && (*head)->value == value ) {
        struct Node *tmp = *head;
        *head = (*head)->next;     /*removed some useless code here*/
        free(tmp);
    }
    struct Node *iterator = *head;
    if(iterator == NULL)
        return;
    while(iterator->next != NULL) {
        if(iterator->next->value == value) {
            struct Node *tmp = iterator->next;
            iterator->next = iterator->next->next; 
            free(tmp);
        }
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }
}
```

Explanation (thanks to comments below):

The Original code tests whether iterator->next should be deleted but mistakenly deleted iterator it self. e.g. 2->1->1, the 2 will be deleted because the next node is 1 but it is actually the 1 that should be deleted.

When deleting an element in an linked list, it is not enough to free the node that should be deleted. It is also necessary to set the previous node's "next" variable to the node after the deleted element.

e.g. 2->1->3 OP's code: 2->Null Nothing->3; Correct: 2->3

P.S.
There are problems with my answer, but it seems that I can't delete my accepted answers.

Better answer from below:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow

Your function is too complicated and has a bug because in the second while loop there is no check whether head is equal to NULL and the loop changes the local variable iterator instead of changing nodes themselves.

The function can be implemented simpler. For example

```
void remove_by_value( struct Node **head, int value ) 
{
    while ( *head )
    {
        if ( ( *head )->value == value )
        {
            struct Node *tmp = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
};

void insert(struct Node **head, const int a[], size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        struct Node *current = ( struct Node * )malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

        current->value = a[i];
        current->next = *head;

        *head = current;
        head = &(*head)->next;
    }
}

void print( struct Node *head ) 
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", head->value );
    }
}

void remove_by_value( struct Node **head, int value ) 
{
    while ( *head )
    {
        if ( ( *head )->value == value )
        {
            struct Node *tmp = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    int a[] = { 2, 1, 1 };

    insert( &head, a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );

    print( head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    remove_by_value( &head, 1 );

    print( head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    remove_by_value( &head, 2 );

    print( head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
2 1 1 
2
```

Comment: Yes, it works, I have arrived at the same solution, eventually:-)

Comment: Why does this version work, but the OP code not work? A pure code answer isn't very useful to future readers.

Comment: @leyanpan This is just a bad code and nothing more.

Comment: @Aemilius  You are mistaken. It does not work.

Comment: Could you say why so that I can learn anyway. @vlad-from-moscow

Comment: @leyanpan Because after the first loop *head can be equal to NULL. As result this statement while(iterator->next != NULL) leads to undefined behavior. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is too complicated and has a bug because in the second while loop there is no check whether `head` is equal to NULL and the loop changes the local variable `iterator` instead of changing nodes themselves.

The function can be implemented simpler. For example

```
void remove_by_value( struct Node **head, int value ) 
{
    while ( *head )
    {
        if ( ( *head )->value == value )
        {
            struct Node *tmp = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
};

void insert(struct Node **head, const int a[], size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        struct Node *current = ( struct Node * )malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

        current->value = a[i];
        current->next = *head;

        *head = current;
        head = &(*head)->next;
    }
}

void print( struct Node *head ) 
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", head->value );
    }
}

void remove_by_value( struct Node **head, int value ) 
{
    while ( *head )
    {
        if ( ( *head )->value == value )
        {
            struct Node *tmp = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    int a[] = { 2, 1, 1 };

    insert( &head, a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );

    print( head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    remove_by_value( &head, 1 );

    print( head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    remove_by_value( &head, 2 );

    print( head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
2 1 1 
2
```

Answer (score 2):

There was a time when programmers had to do this sort of thing a lot, and after you do it enough times your code gets really efficient.  To help keep that ancient art alive, here is what a function like this should look like:

```
void removeByValue(Node **head, int val){
    Node *n;
    while(n=*head) {
        if (n->value == val) {
            *head = n->next;
            free(n);
        } else {
            head = &(n->next);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the first loop of your removal function is OK, but a little clunky. This bit of code is pretty redundant as whatever value `next` is, you're assigning it to `*head`

```
if((*head)->next != NULL)
    *head = (*head)->next;
else
    *head = NULL;
```

But all it's doing is removing the first node whilst it matches the value you're looking for, which isn't particularly useful.

It's the next loop that is the problem as it's not updating your list properly. Imagine your list is 1 -> 2 -> 3 and you're removing 2. You iterate over your list until you get to the middle node. You take a temporary copy of the current node, point yourself at the next one and then free it. Which leaves your list like 1 -> 2???    3 as you haven't updated the previous node to point to the next node.

You can do the whole thing though with just one loop. You use `head` as a way of tracking whatever was pointing at the current node. So at the start of the loop it points at the start of the list. If the node doesn't match, you have it point at whatever the current node's next is pointing at.

If it does match, you again take a temporary copy of the current node, but this time you update `*head` to point to the next node. So it'll maintain the previous connection or start of the list.

```
void remove_by_value(struct Node **head, int value) {
    while( *head!=NULL ) {
        if ((*head)->value == value) {
            struct Node *tmp=*head;
            *head=(*head)->next;
            free(tmp);
        } else {
            head=&((*head)->next);
        }
    }
}
```